Apollo 15 envelopes to the Moon - inspired by Heinlein or coincidence?
Per this article

The Apollo 15 postal covers incident, a 1972 NASA scandal, involved
the astronauts of Apollo 15, who carried about 400 unauthorized postal
covers into space and to the Moon's surface on the Lunar Module
Falcon. Some of the envelopes were sold at high prices by West German
stamp dealer Hermann Sieger, and are known as "Sieger covers".

This is of course, rather reminiscent of the schemes that Delos D. Harriman used to fund his Moon rocket — Harriman has the first rocket made a legal post office and sends stamped envelopes to be cancelled there (or promises to do so, anyway!).
Was the Apollo 15 business directly inspired by Heinlein, or is it a coincidence (perhaps stamped envelopes are an obvious low-mass high-value item for a profit-seeker?)?
Note that the Apollo 15 astronauts were fans, judging from this excerpt of their conversations on the Moon:

167:51:20 Allen: As the space poet Rhysling (the blind poet in Robert
Heinlein's The Green Hills of Earth) would say, we're ready for you to
"come back again to the homes of men on the cool green hills of
Earth."
[Scott - "That's from the Green Hills of Earth. That's one we talked about before the flight. Have you read that one?"]
[Jones - "Oh, yeah! That was a favorite when I was a kid. Had you read it?"]
[Scott - "Sure. (Quoting from memory) 'We pray for one last landing, on the globe that gave us birth. To rest our eyes on fleecy
skies, and the cool green hills of Earth.'"]


(1) Unless one of the astronauts said so, how could we know? (2) They may have read it in RAH, but not remembered where they got the idea. (3) It's a pretty obvious high-value, low-mass, low-complexity, easily-hidden moneymaker. If a definitive answer is possible, look to #1.

Scott is still alive, but probably not too fond of discussing the incident.

I'm hoping that someone out there knows of a memoir or interview that I haven't found
